# Solve $x''+\frac{1}{17} x'=400$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no problem finding the general solution $x_{g} = a+be^{-t/17}$, but I'm not sure how I would get the particular solution.

Since $G(x)=400$ I seek a particular solution in the form $x_{p}=C$, where $C$ is a constant. The only problem is that $x_{p}',x_{p}''=0$. So, if I plug them into the original equations I get $0=400$. Obviously I messed up my solution at some point. Any ideas?

Comment: The particular solution has to be of the form $Cx$ because of this exact reason. You can use the substitution $u=x'$ to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

$$f''(x)=a+bf'(x)$$
$$\frac{f''(x)}{a+bf'(x)}=1$$
$$\int\frac{f''(x)}{a+bf'(x)}dx=x+c_1$$
Set $u=a+bf'(x)$:
$$\int\frac{du}{u}=bx+c$$
$$\ln u=bx+c$$
$$a+bf'(x)=e^{bx+c}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{b}e^{bx+c}-\frac{a}{b}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{c_1}}{b}\int e^{bx}dx-\frac{a}{b}x+c_2$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{b^2}e^{bx+c}-\frac{a}{b}x+c_2$$
Use $a=400$ and $b=-1/17$.

Comment: The idea with the substitution is really nice.

Comment: @MarianG. Thank you very much. I am glad you liked it :)